# Why is this Simple 2d movement lagging so much?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make snake and just tried to add movement to my snake.

Unfortunately this code causes the snake to stop then speed up and makes it unusable.
What I would like to see is the snake moving at a constant speed across the screen without it stuttering and jumping forward.

```
import pygame
import random

DIM = (800, 800)
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode(DIM)
CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
SIZE = 20
GRID = [DIM[0] / SIZE, DIM[1] / SIZE]





class snake:
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = (0, 255, 0)
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 1
        self.direct = 0

    def draw(self, win=WIN):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, (self.x * SIZE, self.y * SIZE, SIZE, SIZE))

    def move(self, direct):
        self.direct = direct
        print(self.direct)
        if self.direct == 1:
            self.x = self.x - 1
        if self.direct == 2:
            self.x = self.x + 1
        if self.direct == 3:
            self.y = self.y - 1
        if self.direct == 4:
            self.y = self.x + 1


def main(win=WIN):
    direction = 0

    running = True
    
    snak = snake()
    while running:
        win.fill((120, 120, 120))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if keys[pygame.K_a]:
                direction = 1
            elif keys[pygame.K_d]:
                direction = 2
            elif keys[pygame.K_w]:
                direction = 3
            elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
                direction = 4
            snak.move(direction)

        snak.draw()
        #CLOCK.tick(10)
        pygame.display.flip()


main()
```

I also tried running it on another computer to see if maybe it was a hardware problem but I came up with the same result.
Thank you for helping.

Comment: What version of pygame do you have installed?

Comment: @DanielCazares pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.9.6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never written in Python before, but I got it working on my MacBook Pro with an Arm chip.

Installed pygame 2.0.2.dev3 and python 3.9.6

Rewrote it a bit:

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

DIM = (800, 800)
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode(DIM)
CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
SIZE = 20
GRID = [DIM[0] / SIZE, DIM[1] / SIZE]
GAME_OVER = False

class snake:
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = (0, 255, 0)
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 1
        self.direct = 0


    def move(self, direct):
        self.direct = direct
        print(self.direct)
        if self.direct == 1:
            self.x = self.x - SIZE
        if self.direct == 2:
            self.x = self.x + SIZE
        if self.direct == 3:
            self.y = self.y - SIZE
        if self.direct == 4:
            self.y = self.y + SIZE

def main(win=WIN):
    direction = 0
    snak = snake()
    while not GAME_OVER:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
              if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                direction = 1
              elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                direction = 2
              elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                direction = 3
              elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                direction = 4
        snak.move(direction)
        win.fill((120, 120, 120))
        pygame.draw.rect(win, snak.color, [snak.x, snak.y, SIZE, SIZE])
        pygame.display.update()
        CLOCK.tick(30)
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

main()
```

You also had a bug on the downward direction key, S, it would jump down because you were adding x+1 to y rather than y+1 to y.

```
        if self.direct == 4:
            self.y = self.x + 1
```

Note how the snak object will move constantly since its under the while loop rather than the for event loop.

Happy to answer any questions.